# classification accuracy with sklearn in percentage

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, metrics, sklearn-pandas

I tried to calculate the accuracy score with sklearn.

```
a = accuracy_score(df['colA'], df2['colA'])
```

I works very well but i would like to have the score in **percentage(%)**

What kind of modification i can do please?

Comment: You can just multiply the result by 100 since the accuracy score returns a value between [0,1].

Comment: @HakanAkgün i want to add the sign(%) eg 20%, 100%

Comment: To just plot right?

Comment: @HakanAkgün yes excatly

Comment: I'm providing an example then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accuracy score is the portion of samples that were correctly classified, out of the total number of samples, so it ranges from 0 to 1.

This can be converted to a percentage by just multiplying it by 100:

```py
    a = accuracy_score(df['colA'], df2['colA'])
    
    print("Current accuracy is {}%".format(a*100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can simply multiply by 100 and format the print as follow:

```
print(f'accuracy: {a*100:.2f}%')
```

This will print the `accuracy` as percentage with 2 decimal precision.

Output:

```
accuracy: 99.56%
```